# Best Practice: Frequent usage of big temporal buffer within function (C++)

Tags: c++, memory-management

I quite often got the problem that I got a function that requires a bigger amount of memory for some internal computations.
The function will be called with a high frequency.
It might be the case that the amount of memory is too big to fit into the stack. Thus I have to allocate and deallocate memory.
However, I am quite concerned about the overhead caused by this frequent, unnecessary allocation / deallocation.

I currently see the following options:

1. allocation / deallocation every time
2. using a static variable for keeping that memory in combination with a shared pointer to ensure safe destruction of the allocated memory
3. using global (or file scope) memory to keep the memory allocated for the whole time.
4. encapsulating the function inside a Class and adding a member variable holding the allocated memory (here I am mostly concerned about

Regarding Approach 3-4: I am mostly concerned that actually the values in this memory are only valid within this function and should only be used there. However, actually the scope of the variable is bigger and misuse or accidential usage of the variables is easily possible. It has to be made clear that it is not intended to use these variables outside of the function.
My favorite right now is option 2.
I would be quite glad to hear your opinion on best practice approaches in this case.

Slighly Modified Question:
Imagine, that we now have a member method instead of a standalone function.
Here my favorite approach number 2 would not work anymore, since all instances of the class would share the same computation buffer. Thus, I think there are only two alternatives:
1. allocation / deallocation every time
2. using a member variable for each plugin to keep the memory allocated.

Regarding approach 2 I got again some mistrust: The member variable could be accessed by all functions within the same class although the intended scope should be only for a temporal computation within this single member function.

Maybe some naming conventions for this variable as well as comments can help:
E.g.

```
...
private:
/** this variable is only intended to be used temporarily within fct1 */
std::shared_ptr<std::array<double, 10000>> tmpBuffer;
...
```

Comment: If the same caller is responsible for most of the frequent calls to your function, one possibility is to have the caller provide the temporary storage your function should use.

Comment: Is threading a possibility? What about reentrancy? If neither is an issue, a global isn't much of a problem. If threading is an issue, `thread_local` buffers could solve it. Reentrancy is where you're effectively forced to allocate separately.

Comment: Since I guess you are not dealing with multithreading, you can simply use a static function local var. You'd pay a small penalty for accessing it, though, due to thread safety of statics. Class-level static will be free from that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach in the "slightly modified" question seems justified.  If you have a function repeatedly operating on some piece of data that gets used in limited ways in some other scopes but is not intended to be accessible to the whole program, that may be a cue that that data and those functions should be tied together as members and methods within the same class.  Once that class is defined, lifetimes for instances of it can be handled more simply by the usual means like scoping, `std::shared_ptr` or similar.

At that point, unless you have further concrete evidence that the scoping and layout of that class are causing problems, it would be wise to trust that the compiler, CPU caches, etc. are making good choices for you until profiling data proves otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose you have a function `F` that wants to use a large temporary buffer `B`.

1. You don't want to allocate and deallocate `B` every time `F` is called, if `F` is called with high frequency.
2. I'm not sure what you mean in the option #2. If `B` is declared static then you don't/shouldn't put it inside a `shared_ptr`. Static variables have program lifetime, which can't/shouldn't be managed by smart pointers.
3. Using a global `B` from performance point of view is essentially the same as using static `B`, except with global other functions can access the `B`, too, which you seem not wanting.
4. You can encapsulate `B` inside a class `C`, construct an instance `S` and pass a reference of `S` as argument to `F`. Other functions won't be able to access `B` unless you also pass `S` to them.

In my opinion, of the above 4 options, you don't want to do #1 for performance reason, #2 is better than #3 for narrower visibility, and #4 seems the most flexible.

By using atomic operations in the accessors of `B` in #4, you may also allow multiple threads to call the function at the same time while sharing access to `B`. Or you may simply use different instances of `C` in threads that should not share the same buffer. It also doesn't matter whether `F` is a static function of a class member method; the behaviors are the same.

The drawback is that `F` now requires an extra parameter (`C& s`) whose lifetime needs to be managed outside of `F` by your program. But this is essentially what you want -- for performance optimization.